# Twice dereferencing 2D array stored as pointer to pointer causes segfault

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I understand why `int (*arr2d)[3]` is good and why `**arr2d` is bad as function arguments for functions expecting to be passed 2d arrays.  I know that a 2d array decays to pointer-to-array and not pointer-to-pointer.  I also know why the `3`, the number of columns, is necessary information for a function that will handle a 2d array (the underlying pointer math of indexing into an array of dimension greater than 1 requires the size of the array along all dimensions after the first).

What I do not know, however, is why the seg fault happens.  If a 2d array can be dereferenced twice to retrieve its first element, why is this not true when its treated as a pointer-to-pointer?  I understand that 2d array is not equivalent to pointer-to-pointer.  I want to know why I can't dereference the latter twice **in this case**. Consider the following two examples.

In the first, a 2d array is passed to a function expecting a pointer-to-pointer, causing seg fault when it is twice dereferenced within said function.

```
void printFirst(int **arr2d) {
    printf("%d\n",**arr2d);
}
void printFirst_corrected(int (*arr2d)[3]) {
    printf("%d\n",**arr2d);
}
int main(void) {
    int arr[3][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    printf("%p\n",arr); // prints some address a0
    printf("%p\n",*arr); // prints the same address a0
    printf("%d\n",**arr); // prints 1
    printFirst_corrected(arr); // works, prints 1
    printFirst(arr); // why does this fail? (seg fault, core dumped)
}
```

In the second, a 2d array is cast to a pointer-to-pointer and then twice dereferenced, causing seg fault.

```
int main(void) {
    int arr[][3] = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6},{7,8,9}};
    int **nums2 = (int**)arr;
    printf("%p\n",arr); // prints some address a0
    printf("%p\n",*arr); // prints the same address a0
    printf("%d\n\n",**arr); // prints 1
    printf("%p\n",nums2); // prints a0
    printf("%p\n",*nums2); // prints 0x200000001
    printf("%d\n",**nums2); // fails, seg fault (core dumped)
}
```

Comment: `printFirst(arr);` is a constraint violation. If you're not seeing error messages from the compiler then you need to reconfigure your compiler.   (The results of running any executable produced as a result are meaningless)

Comment: Suggest reading [C FAQ Chapter 6](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)

Comment: I understand that it's not 'correct', that nobody should do this.  But if a 2d array name is a pointer to the first 1d array, then when I dereference twice, even if I've cast the 2d array to pointer-to-pointer, why do I get a seg fault?  The double dereference clearly works without the cast.

Comment: Undefined behaviour means anything can happen . And the array name is not a pointer. (This is a common lie)

Comment: `int **` means "pointer to pointer".  But `(int **)arr` does not actually point to a pointer variable. It points to memory where there are some `int` objects. Arrays and pointers are different.  When you make a pointer point at memory that doesn't contain an instance of the right type of object, all bets are off

Comment: I think I see what you're saying with the '(int **)arr does not point to a pointer...it points to memory where there are int objects'.  I also get that the array name is not a pointer.  That being said, I did dereference it twice successfully... So what the hell.  Also, how can it have a value of address a0 and when I dereference it the value a0 is returned?  new question?

Comment: if you make an expression that denotes an array, and use it when a pointer is expected, it is implicitly converted to a temporary pointer pointing to that array's first element.  those tepmporary pointers are what you are dereferencing in the `int arr[3][3];  **arr` case . `**arr` means `arr[0][0]`, that's how `[]` operator is defined.